# WSDL XML Link issue

Tags: c++, soap, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I have compiled a wsdl that displays the following request message which works:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <tempuri2:BillInquiry xmlns:tempuri2="http://BillPayment_SOAP">
            <ESB_Header>
                <requestId>327823792977</requestId>
                <destSysOprName>ATM_BILL_INQ</destSysOprName>
                <tranTypeCode>       </tranTypeCode>
                <transmissionDateTime>20231005232051</transmissionDateTime>
                <RRN>327823792977</RRN>
                <deliveryChannelName>ATM</deliveryChannelName>
                <tenantId>ZyLA0LlEzox7Nb9yMUMGeQ==</tenantId>
            </ESB_Header>
            <billerID>ZONG0002</billerID>
            <feeFlag>N</feeFlag>
            <feeAmount>0</feeAmount>
            <stanID>792977</stanID>
            <RRN>327823792977</RRN>
            <consumerNo>11122233344</consumerNo>
            <channelId>117602</channelId>
        </tempuri2:BillInquiry>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

when I try to execute this message, it provides a very odd error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><NS1:Fault xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>-1</faultcode><faultstring>Exception Ouccured</faultstring></NS1:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error^M
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8^M
Server: IBM App Connect Enterprise^M
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 11:45:25 GMT^M
Content-Length: 309^M
Connection: close^M
^M
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><NS1:Fault xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>-1</faultcode><faultstring>Exception Ouccured</faultstring></NS1:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

the message works if I change the site position to the first line:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" tempuri2:BillInquiry xmlns:tempuri2="http://BillPayment_SOAP">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ESB_Header>
                <requestId>327823792977</requestId>
                <destSysOprName>ATM_BILL_INQ</destSysOprName>
                <tranTypeCode>       </tranTypeCode>
                <transmissionDateTime>20231005232051</transmissionDateTime>
                <RRN>327823792977</RRN>
                <deliveryChannelName>ATM</deliveryChannelName>
                <tenantId>ZyLA0LlEzox7Nb9yMUMGeQ==</tenantId>
            </ESB_Header>
            <billerID>ZONG0002</billerID>
            <feeFlag>N</feeFlag>
            <feeAmount>0</feeAmount>
            <stanID>792977</stanID>
            <RRN>327823792977</RRN>
            <consumerNo>11122233344</consumerNo>
            <channelId>117602</channelId>
        </tempuri2:BillInquiry>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to sort of make this line change position in code? Because I searched and performed some code changes but no luck. The wsdl compiled creates various files. I attempted to change the Proxy file of my wsdl but it instead created errors which I then reverted back.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message here.

Comment: I attached the screenshot highlighted in blue. I will try to type it in.

Comment: Why have you tagged C++?

Comment: I compiled the wsdl in linux vm using wdl2h and soapcpp2 which then creates the Service and Proxy files in .h and .cpp as well as an nsmap and req xml and response xml. I thought this could potentially be a c++ fault so I tagged in c++.

Comment: Is your server code in C++? If yes, then please provide some logs.